# mmap virtual memory (HDD) and main memory (RAM) allocation

Tags: c++, c, memory, mmap

I'm working with `mmap()` function.
I Confiused about something in `mmap` flags.

`MAP_SHARED` with fd → **Usage** To allocated virtual memory which uses Hard Drive (HDD) and physical memory (RAM) will not be used. I allocated 2 GB using this flag with `fd` and my RAM remained unused (what I expected).

`MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS` with (fd = -1) → **Usage** To allocated main memory, which is RAM. I allocated 2 GB using this flag and I filled it with something then I checked my RAM usage and yes, 2 GB in use ...

Now my point, first method (`MAP_SHARED`) uses virtual memory (HDD) and second method (`MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS`) uses main memory (RAM) so 100% the second method MUST be different in performance since RAM is too much faster than HDD ... am I right ? If I'm right, so why `mmap` function is called as a '**virtual memory allocation**' function !!!??? By flag `MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS` allocates main memory (RAM) too !!!!!!!

If `MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS` does not guarantee to provide 'main memory (RAM)', what should I do to allocated memory from main memory (RAM) ?!

What I got from `mmap`, `mmap` checks if a private flag (`MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS`) is provided, checks for unused RAM space and provides memory from RAM (main memory), if there is available space on RAM and if there isn't, it uses virtual memory (HDD). Right !?

**Update**

I decide to put 2 tests. one with `MAP_SHARED` and one with `MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS`

**test 1** Memory allocation based on a file (`MAP_SHARED`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>

int
main() {
    double time_spent = 0.0;
    int fd = open("/home/alireza/Documents/mem", O_CREAT|O_RDWR);
    ftruncate(fd, (4294967296));
    char * memory = mmap(NULL, (4294967296), PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    if(memory == MAP_FAILED) {
        printf("(%d)", errno);
        exit(0);
    }
    write(0, "started ...\n", sizeof("started ...\n")-1);
    clock_t begin = clock();
    for (long i = 0; i < (4294967296); i++) {
        memory[i] = 'c';
    }
    clock_t end = clock();
    write(0, "done\n", sizeof("done\n")-1);
    time_spent += (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("time (%f)\n", time_spent);
    exit(0);
}
```

**Result (9 seconds (since it uses virtual memory (HDD)) !!!)**

```
started ...
done
time (9.087634)
```

**test 2** Memory allocation using RAM (`MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>

int
main() {
    double time_spent = 0.0;
    char * memory = mmap(NULL, (4294967296), PROT_WRITE|PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    if(memory == MAP_FAILED) {
        printf("(%d)", errno);
        exit(0);
    }
    write(0, "started ...\n", sizeof("started ...\n")-1);
    clock_t begin = clock();
    for (long i = 0; i < (4294967296); i++) {
        memory[i] = 'c';
    }
    clock_t end = clock();
    write(0, "done\n", sizeof("done\n")-1);
    time_spent += (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("time (%f)\n", time_spent);
    exit(0);
}
```

**Result (1 second)**

```
started ...
done
time (1.405220)
```

So `mmap` is not just virtual memory allocation (HDD). It's main memory allocation too, and it decides it based on the flag ! So using `MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag to use real memory (RAM) is completely different from using SHARED flag !

Comment: This sounds like a question about the terminology. It may help to understand that one of the use case for `mmap` is to map the same file in multiple processes to share that memory space to allow inter process communication. If you just want to allocate memory normally, you can use `new`, `std::make_unique`, `std::allocator` and other portable solutions instead of `mmap` unless you are doing something very specific.

Comment: Here shared doesn't mean the location of the memory, instead it means processes can share it with each other.

Comment: It would be a neat trick which "uses Hard Drive" but "memory (RAM) will not be used". That's not how `MAP_SHARED` works. Which specific part of `mmap`'s documentation led you to draw thijs conclusion? Can you quote that documentation, verbatim?

Comment: Sorry, I changed 'shared' memory to 'virtual' memory. I mean 'virtual' memory not 'shared' because a main memory (RAM) could be shared too.

Comment: All of the memory userland processes can access is 'virtual'.  Do you mean "mapped from a file"?  Because the `MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag is explicitly telling `mmap` "I don't want this mapped from a particular file; I just want it to be treated as if it was".  I would also point out that `MAP_PRIVATE` and `MAP_ANONYMOUS` are orthogonal.  It's perfectly valid to specify  `MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS` to get an anonymous shared mapping.

Comment: Very Related: [Understanding Virtual Address, Virtual Memory and Paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290347/understanding-virtual-address-virtual-memory-and-paging)

Comment: @Mooing Duck No since I'm talking about `mmap`. what `mmap` do.

Comment: @HelloMachine: `mmap` allocates virtual memory, that may be backed by a file, or it may be other shared virtual memory, or it may be unshared virtual memory.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: so why when we using `MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS`, it allocates memory from RAM !!? So it's not always 'virtual memory'

Comment: virtual memory does not mean disk. It can be RAM, disk, or not allocated. Its just the address space of the process.

Comment: mmap doesn't actually allocate any RAM until you use it. If you mmap 4 GB and use only 4 KB, then that much RAM will be actually allocated. The OS can seamlessly use a swap file for pages that don't fit in RAM. Also in file-backed mode the OS still allocates RAM, for caching purposes. So the boundary between file-backed and not is really blurred. And it's all exactly the same process in the kernel, it's virtual memory.

Comment: @stark but in every place I read about virtual memory, they said 'HDD' ...

Comment: Then you are reading the wrong places.

Comment: @rustyx I know about page size and each 4 Kb must be filled to count as used space ... So you're telling me that OS decides to use a file-backed mode or real RAM.... a question ! How MySQL has 'MEMORY' database type ? 'MEMORY' means real RAM usage. So there must be a way to use actual memory (RAM (not just for caching)) instead of file-backed memory .... no ?

Comment: I think you've got some misconceptions here.  mmap'ing a file doesn't mean that RAM will not be used - it means that whatever RAM is used will be *backed* by the file on the disk. The RAM will be filled with the file contents before you read it, and any modifications will be written back to the file when you are done (if not before).

Comment: @NateEldredge correct, but why using `MAP_SHARED` flag with fd takes 9 seconds (copy 4 billion characters) and using `MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag without fd takes 1 second (copy 4 billion characters) ?!!!

Comment: Where are you copying to or from?

Comment: @NateEldredge you can see the examples in my question. I used `mmap` with `MAP_SHARED` and a file (`fd`) and I copied 4 billion characters into the allocated space. It took 9 seconds. Then I used `mmap` with `MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS` without `fd` and I copied the same (4 billion characters into the allocated space), It took only 1 second. So using `MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS` is not about FILE any more ! since using `MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS` flag is about directly RAM usage.

Comment: `MAP_ANONYMOUS` mappings are backed by swap.